# How to setup Vim-Latex to run only 1 instance of SumatraPDF?

Tags: windows, vim, viewers

I'm trying to setup vim-latex plugin to do default compile and view using PDF, with SumatraPDF as the default reader. Here's the configuration I made in `.vimrc`:

```
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'SumatraPDF'
```

I've set the PATH variable to points to SumatraPDF installation directory. At this point, `\ll` and `\lv` worked perfectly. The only thing that bugged me is that everytime I do `\lv`, vim-latex automatically open a new instance of SumatraPDF. I use other editor like TexStudio or TeXnicCenter with no problem (view PDF only open one instance). What am I doing wrong? Is there something I have to add in the `.vimrc`?

I've search everywhere with no result, but if I'm wrong, please just point me to the link.

Comment: In the SumatraPDF help file you will see the command line option `-reuse-instance`.

Comment: @DanieEls It works wonderfully now. Thank you. Could you post your comment as anwer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SumatraPDF can be called with commandline options, see [help manual](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/manual.html). The option

```
-reuse-instance
```

will do the trick

---

The final modification that made it works is this:

```
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'SumatraPDF -reuse-instance'
```