# Use SumatraPDF as default viewer for vim-latex

Tags: vim-latex

Based on an 5 year old post, [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45369/how-to-setup-vim-latex-to-run-only-1-instance-of-sumatrapdf), I tried to use SumatraPDF as a viewer for vim-latex with following commands in my vimrc file:

```
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF -reuse-instance'
```

However, I get the following error: [image]

I tried to compile this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5 in, 9.5in}]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction} 
Some random text
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you have a look at this post https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/75